# Binding DropDownListFor In foreach , ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Here is my code :

ViewModel

```
public class FooViewModel{
   public Guid BarId { set;get }
}
```

View :

```
@model IEnumerable<FooViewModel>
@foreach (var c in Model)
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(o => c.BarId , (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BarCollection)
    </div>
}
```

the problem is `DropDownListFor` create the options completely but binding doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate controls for items in a collection. If you inspect the html you will see that you have duplicate `name` attributes without indexers (and also duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html). You need a `for` loop of a custom `EditorTemplate` for `FooViewModel`. Using a `for` loop (your model must implement `IList<T>`)

```
@model IList<FooViewModel>
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].BarId, ....)
}
```

Note the html will now be

```
<select name="[0].BarId" ..>
<select name="[1].BarId" ..>
```

etc.

Comment: Side note: There are a few other issues with this including that if your editing existing items that have a `BarId` value set, then the first option will still always be selected when you display the view (although it will post back correctly). But until I see your controller code I can;t show you the correct way to fix it - but essentially you need to generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration